# fs.watch is returning null for the file name

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
fs.watch(*file*, function(event, filename){
  console.log('event ' + event);
  console.log('filename ' + filename);
});
```

when the file changes this is outputting:

```
event:  change
filename: null
```

Any ideas what could cause this? I'm on OSX.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener):

> When watching a directory, providing filename argument in the callback
>   is not supported on every platform (currently it's only supported on
>   Linux and Windows). Even on supported platforms filename is not always
>   guaranteed to be provided. Therefore, don't assume that filename
>   argument is always provided in the callback, and have some fallback
>   logic if it is null.